# Implementing a high-scale scheduler on a database

Tags: postgresql, redis, database-partitioning

We have a Postgres DB with a table of tens of millions of rows.
We also have a scheduler (app code) that runs on those rows and querying for specific assets. Usually what we need is 30days old items there.

We started to scale, and the scheduler is very slow.

What is the best approach to scale with maintaining a good performance? Using a different DB? Redis? ES? Partitioning the Postgres?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't actually provide any information so people can help you. What scale? How is your schedule modelled? How often is the schedule updated? How often does the scheduler run? This is probably a design process rather than a question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually what we need is 30days old items there.

That's the part of your question that's actually relevant. Postgresql, when used appropriately, should have absolutely no trouble performing a simple `WHERE` query with tens of millions of rows. The cost of index lookups grows logarithmically.

To take a stab in the dark: If you are performing date calculations for every row in your WHERE statement, performance will indeed be abysmal. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE AGE(CREATED_AT) > INTERVAL '30 days';
```

...is a rather bad idea. Instead, calculate the date cutoff once, and statically use it in the comparison.

If your query is really more complicated, you could also look into `expression indices`. It's overkill for the example above, and it adds some overhead to all data-modifying operations, but would make a query as the one above perform as well as the static variant.

In any case: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` is your friend, and posting its output will make you even more friends here.